# reload PageFragment data after update fields in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter, page-fragments

I used [this article](http://www.anjadev.com/all/programming/android_development/android-implement-list-view-in-combination-with-swipe-view/) 
and I have a question.

In PageFragment (extends Fragment) I have some fields that load from DB (sqlite)
and this fragment have a button that after click, update table in db.
I want to reload fragment to show updated data (without swiping).
I know that android keep states in memory, but I need to show updated fields whithout swiping.

I try to use POSITION_NONE, setOffscreenPageLimit, notifyDataSetChanged, detach, attach and etc..but none of them work and I confused about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a more proper way of doing that would be to put the initial update logic in separate method and call the method after updating the db.

```
public void onCreateView(){
    //your view creation and inflation
    //call populateUI after inflation here
}

public void onResume(){
    //or here
}

//take data from someplace and populate your UI may be from database
public void populateUI(){
  //get values and set fields 
}

public void onClick(View v){
    //the button click
    //update db
    //then
    populateUI();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I use wrong method to solve the problem. With the help of the method described by you, my problem was solved.

Comment: glad it helped :-)